# magento input field cursor issue in IOS

Tags: magento-1.9, css, iphone

When I click input field to give email, and password cursor is going down.

Please find the below screen-shot. 
Please let me know how to fix this issue.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the discussion below?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737503/mobile-safari-input-caret-does-not-scroll-along-with-overflow-scrolling-touch

Answer (score 2):

Please try below css:

```
.block-search input {
    position: relative;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    text-align: start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
body.modal-popup{
   position: fixed;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

hope this works..